# How to filter in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to do a filtering operation on id. I want the data with an id of 3 to be skipped.

**Example**

```js
const id=3;

const data =[
{id:1},
{id:2},
{id:3},
{id:4},
{id:5},
];

// the result i want

[{id:1},{id:2},{id:4},{id:5}]
```

How can I do this in Mongoose?

Comment: You cannot filter an entry from a list inside a document unless you set up an aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 1):

```
yourModelName.find({ id: { $ne: 3 } })
```

**$ne**: Not equals to

More on find method: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-find

ne operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Answer (score 0):

[Find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-find) is your friend. You can apply a condition the the fields you want to search by. In this case it's `id`. `$ne` is a query condition, meaning Not Equal to the value given.

Your query will look something like this:

```js
const number = 3
const result = await users.find({ id : { $ne: number } })
```